# Can we disable zoom on highchart graph while graph is loading

Tags: highcharts

Can we disable zoom on highchart graph while graph is loading.
I have multiple graphs therfore would like to disable the zoom option until all graphs gets loaded.

Comment: In other words you need to enable zoom dynamically, after all charts are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change zoomType of a chart dynamically, but it is not a part of official API. That way after all charts are loaded you will be able to change their zoomType from none to some.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            minRange: 1
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        }]
    });

    function enableZoom(zoomType) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
            zoomX = /x/.test(zoomType),
            zoomY = /y/.test(zoomType);

            chart.options.zoomType = zoomType;

            chart.pointer.zoomX = zoomX;
            chart.pointer.zoomY = zoomY;

            chart.pointer.zoomHor = zoomX;
            chart.pointer.zoomVert = zoomY;
    }

    $('#zoomX').click(function () {
        enableZoom('x');
    });

    $('#zoomY').click(function () {
        enableZoom('y');        
    });

    $('#zoomXY').click(function () {
        enableZoom('xy');        
    });

    $('#noZoom').click(function () {
        enableZoom('');        
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pearp126/

Comment: Thanks It works, but facing problem that i am using xtype:highchart instead of  $('#container').highcharts({, so not getting object after chart render. Pls help

Comment: @cheeku There are other ways of getting the chart, like using non-jQuery cunstructor - http://jsfiddle.net/pearp126/1/. Other way is to use a global array `Highcharts.charts` that holds all charts from current page/frame.

Comment: I have multiple graphs rendering in a loop and have to use Xtype:highchart for preparing graph. Moto is to enabling zoom after all graphs gets loaded                   Highcharts.Chart.prototype.callbacks.push(function (wchart) {              is working for last graph only

Comment: @cheeku Could you post live example, like jsFiddle? How are you creating the charts? How is your data loaded?

Comment: Thank you! It works very good in 'moxiegroup' wrapper for GWT

Answer (score 0):

you can do so by simple setting zoomType as null in your chart config

```
zoomType: null
```

See the documentation [here for more details](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming)

Comment: The point is that it's pretty difficult to update the chart settings after the chart is rendered. (Usually you need to recreate your whole chart)

Comment: its before chart rendering , also setExtreme can be used if a particular range need to display .

Comment: oh really, then its difficult to acheive this functionality. As requirement is to disable zooming until all graphs gets loaded

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi Zoom functionality needs to be enabled after the data is loaded, according to the question.

Comment: In that case , use setExterem so that while loading all the data display in desired range and after load user may zoom if he wants. hope I understand your question.

Comment: please advice someone

Comment: so if I use setExtreme then user can't drag the graph?? i mean can't zoom the graph?

Comment: actually if i zoom the first graph then subgraphs also gets zoomed, so if i zzom first graph while subgraphs are loading then it gives us inconsistent data

Answer (score 0):

Basically the only thing you need to get done is removing the chart and replacing it with one with the settings you like.

See the code below:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

function renderChart(){
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart.options);
    chart.render();
}
```

Once you want to enable zooming (or any other setting):

```
$('#container').highcharts().options.chart.zoomType = 'xy';
renderChart();
```

*To be honest I'm not sure what happens to the old chart. Hopefully it's just overwritten and doesn't it impose a big memory issue.*

I created a fiddle you can find [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CorstianBoerman/rwcs3a37/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can stop the "selection" event (zoom), when the loading label of the chart is displayed.

Using the default Highcharts function `.showLoading()` for show the loading label, and the default variable `loadingShown`, for verify is the loading label is displayed or not.

So, by using the function `.showLoading()`, let's say before doing an AJAX request, and validating with the variable `loadingShown` if the loading label is displayed or not, we can stop the selection event.

Another way, is to use a thirdparty loading mask, and add it to the chart's container.

In the next example you'll find how to cancel the zoom using the `.showLoading()` function and how to use jQuery plugin: pLoading https://github.com/joseshiru/p-loading (for show the loading mask)

```
$(function () {
          var setEvents;
          var chart;
            $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {        
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                      renderTo: 'container',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        events: {
                         selection: function () {
                           //Quit the selection event, while the loading spinner is displayed.
                           if (chart.loadingShown) {
                             return false;
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Exchange rate'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            fillColor: {
                                linearGradient: {
                                    x1: 0,
                                    y1: 0,
                                    x2: 0,
                                    y2: 1
                                },
                                stops: [
                                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                ]
                            },
                            marker: {
                                radius: 2
                            },
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            threshold: null
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{
                        type: 'area',
                        name: 'USD to EUR',
                        data: data
                    }]
                });
         });
          setEvents = function () {
            var $showLoadingBtn = $('.show-loading');
                var $hideLoadingBtn = $('.hide-loading');
                var $showExternalMask = $('.show-toggle-mask');
                var $hideExternalMask = $('.hide-toggle-mask');

                $showLoadingBtn.on('click.showLoading', function () {
                 chart.showLoading();
                });

                $hideLoadingBtn.on('click.hideLoading', function () {
                 chart.hideLoading();
                });

                $showExternalMask.on('click.toggleMask', function () {
                 $('#container').ploading({action: 'show'});
                });

                $hideExternalMask.on('click.toggleMask', function () {
                 $('#container').ploading({action: 'hide'});
                });
            }();
        });
```

Example in jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8p2fzbxw/3/